# What's the difference between a class and a constructor

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently going through the android basics with compose course and I'm learning about classes. I had trouble understanding what a constructor, I don't know what's a constructor or why is it used and I don't really understand secondary constructors. But at least I know that the primary constructor is the same thing as the class declaration (correct me if I'am wrong), so whenever I declare a class I am declaring a primary constructor.

Now I am learning modifiers and for some reason that I don't understand, the syntax for constructors is: `class Name modifier constructor ()` but for classes it's: `modifier class Name()`

So I think that my idea about a class being the same as a primary constructor is wrong? If so, what's the difference?

```
open class SmartDevice protected constructor (val name: String, val category: String) {

    ...

}
```

```
internal open class SmartDevice(val name: String, val category: String) {

    ...

}
```

These are code snippets from the course, why is the first one considered a constructor and the second one a class?
Thank you for reading and sorry if it seems too basic.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but these are basic programming concepts that anyone with even the slightest programming experience should know. I highly suggest to do some beginner's courses in software development instead of straight diving into making an application. For this particular question this should answer your question, and I highly suggest looking through other sections on that website too to get a grasp of how things work: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html . Try reading some documentation before straight away asking others about how things work

Answer (score 0):

Both snippets define classes, not constructors. Constructors are defined within classes and are used to initialize instances of the class.
The primary constructor in Kotlin is declared within the class header, following the class name. It's not explicitly named like in some other languages.
The difference between the two snippets lies in the access modifier (protected vs. internal) and their visibility (open allows subclassing).
In Kotlin, classes can have properties and methods, which define the behavior and state of instances of that class. Constructors are used to initialize the properties of instances when they are created.

Comment: Not exactly right. Both snippets define classes, *including* their constructors.